# Enable Guest checkout in magento admin order create

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-order-create

I was wondering if it is possible and feasible to do.

I am in a need of `Guest Checkout` for **admin order checkout**.

Anyone have any idea, please suggest.

Answer (score 6):

When you say you want a Guest Checkout, I presume you mean you want them to be able to setup an order without providing the customer a login?

You should be able to acheive this out of the box with no requirement for further modules. Simply go to Sales -> Orders and click Create New Order

On the next screen you will be presented with a Select a customer, where you can create a new customer which may need you to select the website it will be associated with. At that point you just fill out the customer contact details in Billing & Shipping, as well as adding the various order elements (products, shipping etc)

Comment: I don't want to create any customer, just do checkout without any customer, I can put custom email though.

Comment: If you wish to provide no customer details that could be complex, especially with shipping being calculated on shipping address. You could perhaps create a internal account to associate them with.

Comment: I don't need shipping details as well. It's for my in store sale.

Comment: Ah that sounds fine, then I suggest you simply create a new customer and give the details of the physical store, then just associate all orders to that account using the above process.

Comment: I had have put this in second option. Was looking for where I don't need to mention any address, no shipping etc, which will make it easy and quick process.

Comment: @AdarshKhatri Did you get any solution for your query?
Would be great if you can share the solutions if you already found that as I am in a same requirement!

Comment: Your solution doesn't answer the OQ. Although, I liked the idea of creating a dummy customer. But this is out of my business policy. It has to be guest checkout if customer is guest for other business logics.

Answer (score 0):

I need to test the guest order because the store is configured to Amazon and I don't have frontend.

I manage to do this in the following way.

1. Create an order with adding a new customer.
2. Press the reorder button.
3. In a new tab - delete that customer.
4. Submit the order.
5. The order is created now is a guest order.

Hope this will help you.